# Redirect specific URLs to an alternate page

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a few URLs that are now 404ing due to products expiring, and I need to redirect them to a related page that does exist.

e.g.

http://www.example.com/package-product.php?id=72 to http://www.example.com/best-sellers/
 http://www.example.com/package-product.php?id=36 to http://www.example.com/bedroom-furniture/

etc.

As I understand it, I can't do this with a Redirect 301 because of the GET param, and the examples I've seen for rewrite seem to be a bit more generic and use a placeholder for the params - I need to send a specific URL to a specific alternative.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it the way @BobLiu suggested - i.e. to do it in PHP itself.

If that's not possible if you really want a rewrite solution, you can look at the QUERY_STRING variable available to mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=72$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/best-sellers/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just say on the package-product.php page something like:

switch ($_GET['id'])
{
  case 72:
  [do redirect url1];

case 36:
  [do redirect url2];

etc...etc..
}

Comment: Unfortunately it's not just the product page that needs it, there's quite a few other pages as well - I didn't write the site, I've just been asked to maintain it.